# Using HTML WebStorage to have multiple username and passwords

Tags: javascript, html, web-storage

I am using WebStorage to make a simple login system with username/password. (I don't know if this is the best way.)
It is working, but the problem is, it only works with one username and password. How do I make it so that it can store multiple usernames/passwords? Or perhaps I should be using a different system to do this?
Code:

```
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
    <input type="text" placeholder="input username here" id="textbox">
    <input type="text" placeholder="input password here" id="textbox2">
    <input type="button" value="sign up" onclick="signup()">
    <br>
    <input type="text" placeholder="input username here" id="textbox3">
    <input type="text" placeholder="input password here" id="textbox4">
    <input type="button" value="login" onclick="login()">

    <p id="result"></p>

    <br>
    <br>
    <div id="settings">
        <h1>Settings</h1>
        <br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="background color" id="bgc">
        <br>
        <input type="button" onclick="changeSettings()" value="Change settings">
    </div>
    <script>
        function changeSettings() {
            if(loggedIn == true) {
                if(typeof(Storage)!= "undefined") {
                    var backg = document.getElementById("bgc").value;
                    if(backg!="") {
                        localStorage.setItem("backgroundColor", backg);
                        document.body.style.background = localStorage.getItem("backgroundColor");
                    } else {
                        alert("Enter a color.")
                    }
                } else {
                    alert("No support.")
                }
            } else {
                alert("You must be logged in to do that.")
            }
        }

        function loadSettings() {
            if(typeof(Storage)!="undefined") {
                document.body.style.background = localStorage.getItem("backgroundColor");
            } else {
                alert("No support.")
            }
        }

        function signup() {
            if(typeof(Storage)!= "undefined") {
                var username = document.getElementById("textbox").value;
                var password = document.getElementById("textbox2").value;
                if(username!="" && password!="") {
                    localStorage.setItem("username", username);
                    localStorage.setItem("password", password);
                } else {
                    alert("Please enter a valid username and password.")
                }
            } else {
                alert("No support.")
            }
        }

        function login() {
            if(typeof(Storage)!= "undefined") {
                var username = localStorage.getItem("username");
                var password = localStorage.getItem("password");
                var usernameInput = document.getElementById("textbox3").value;
                var passwordInput = document.getElementById("textbox4").value;
                if(usernameInput!="" && passwordInput!="") {
                    if(usernameInput == username && passwordInput == password) {
                        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Logged in!";
                        loggedIn = true;
                        loadSettings();
                    } else {
                        document.getElementById("result").innerHTML = "Wrong password/username!";
                    }
                } else {
                    alert("Please enter a valid username and password.")
                }
            } else {
                alert("No support.")
            }
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

ps: sorry if it's messy :p

Comment: You should be using server side to store and validate usernames and passwords.
Having the user to signup and validate on user side, willl only work in his existing broswer session (so if user move pc or clear cache it will need to signup again) 
Also This logic in the frontend is very insecure since I can change the code and grant my self access.

Comment: The more risky part of it, is that any script running in your page can also access these values (e.g ads) and that unfortunately, we know internet users often reuse the same credentials, making your website an easy leaking source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should probably be using SQL if you want to store user inputs such as Usernames and Passwords.

[Hashing & Password Storage](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=z8tUW8Z96dI)

Good video to watch if your trying to learn Databases! 
:)

Answer (score 0):

Not a good way to store the plain username/password in localStorage. anyone can change those value. Since you check the login using

```
localStorage.setItem("username", username);
localStorage.setItem("password", password);

var username = localStorage.getItem("username");
var password = localStorage.getItem("password");

usernameInput == username && passwordInput == password
```

This login condition can make true using different ways.

Found [this](https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-ins-and-outs-of-token-based-authentication) article from the Google, Hope you'll get some idea to do in 
 secure way :)